# More efficient way to do multivariable True/False arguments in Python

Tags: python

I have a function where there can be many true or false variables, in the function I don't want to write out all potential options for which ones could be true / false and what would happen. This is what I have right now, but as I add more variables this will get very long.

```
    def run_preprocess(self, lowercase = False, alphanumeric = False, stopwords = False, lemma = False):
    #what is a better way to do this?
    """
    Function to select preprocessing steps from Preprocess class and automatically alter given dataframe
    :param lower: lowercase text
    :param alphanumeric: removing all non alphanumeric characters from text
    :return: preprocessed dataframe
    """
    
         if lowercase and alphanumeric and stopwords and lemma:
            PreProcess.lower(self)
            PreProcess.remove_non_alphanumeric(self)            
            Preprocess._remove_stopwords(self)
            Preprocess.lemmatize(self)
        elif lowercase and alphanumeric:
            PreProcess.lower(self)
            PreProcess.remove_non_alphanumeric(self)
        elif lowercase:
            PreProcess.lower(self)
        elif alphanumeric:
            PreProcess.remove_non_alphanumeric(self)
        elif stopwords:
            Preprocess._remove_stopwords(self)
        elif lemma:
            Preprocess.lemmatize(self)

        self.df = PreProcess.return_df(self)
```

I want to only write out what each variable should do if true one time while reading multiple true statements in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each condition is simply saying that you need to call a specific function, then you can pretty easily just pull out each condition into its own block:

```py
def run_preprocess(self, lowercase = False, alphanumeric = False, stopwords = False, lemma = False):
    """
    Function to select preprocessing steps from Preprocess class and automatically alter given dataframe
    :param lower: lowercase text
    :param alphanumeric: removing all non alphanumeric characters from text
    :return: preprocessed dataframe
    """
    if lowercase:
        PreProcess.lower(self)

    if alphanumeric:
        PreProcess.remove_non_alphanumeric(self)

    if stopwords:
        Preprocess._remove_stopwords(self)

     if lemma:
        Preprocess.lemmatize(self)

    self.df = PreProcess.return_df(self)
```

The only time you would need to combine them together (like `lowercase and alphanumeric and stopwords and lemma`) is if you would need to do something different if all of those conditions are true.

For example, if you passed options for `numeric` and `alphabetical` that required whatever value must only contain numbers and only contain letters than you might want to raise an exception:

```py
def run_preprocess(self, numeric: False, alphabetical: False):
    if numeric and alphabetical:
        raise Exception("conflicting options")
    # do other things
```

Comment: If I do it the first way and 2 or more things are true it will only do the first if statement, and won't read any of the other if statements. I need it to read each if statement

Comment: If they were chain in an `elif` you are corect. But since each conditional is in its own `if` statement, python will check `lowercase` and run `PreProcess.lower(self)` then check `alphanumeric` and run `PreProcess.remove_non_alphanumeric(self)` and so on. Test out the code and you should each block is executed when its parameter is `True`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some check for possible invalid combinations (?).

But doing each thing only once is an easy thing:

```
if lowercase:
    PreProcess.lower(self)
if alphanumeric:
    PreProcess.remove_non_alphanumeric(self)
if stopwords:
    PreProcess._remove_stopwords(self)
if lemma:
    PreProcess.lemmatize(self)

self.df = PreProcess.return_df(self)
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: In this case 2 or more things are true it will only do the first if statement, and won't read any of the other if statements. I need it to read each if statement

Comment: No it won't. It would if it were an `elif` chain but as these are all just normal `if`'s each condition will be checked regardless wether any other condition was true before or not.